# RethinkDB Polygon.includes

Tags: rethinkdb

Why this RethinkDB query

```
r.polygon(r.point(0,0), r.point(0,10), r.point(10,10), r.point(10,0)).includes(r.point(10,10))
```

returns **true** and this query

```
r.polygon(r.point(0,0), r.point(0,10), r.point(10,10), r.point(10,0)).includes(r.point(10,9))
```

returns **false**?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a floating-point rounding artifact either in the values themselves or in the intersection algorithm. In general intersection and inclusions aren't well defined for points exactly on the outside lines of a polygon. It's like using equality comparison for limited-precision floating point numbers.

I you replace the longitude of the point by a number minimally smaller than 10, you should be getting stable results.